# How to deactivate a codeblock in a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I want to write ...`<p>it starts with <?php and ends with ?>..</p>` in a paragraph but my code editor sees it as an PHP code.

I know we use escape character `\` in Python for this but it did not work on HTML. What should I use for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use HTML escape characters:

```
<p>it starts with &#60;&#63;php and ends with &#63;&#62;..</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode HTML often just by encoding the angle brackets:

`&lt;` => `<`

`&gt;` => `>`